# Highlighting Gridview Rows but not the pager row (ASP.Net, jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I use the following function to highlight a gridview row when the mouse is hovered over the row:-

```
    function pageLoad() {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".Gridview tr").mouseover(function() { $(this).addClass("over"); }).mouseout(function() { $(this).removeClass("over"); });
        });
    }
```

This works fine for a gridview without paging but when the gridview has paging implemented the pager row gets highlighted when the mouse passes over it.

Can anyone help with suggestions as to how I can prevent the pager row being highlighted on mouseover?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding :

```
PagerStyle-CssClass="pager"
```

to your grid view markup and update your js to :

```
 function pageLoad() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".Gridview tr:not(.pager)").mouseover(function() { $(this).addClass("over"); }).mouseout(function() { $(this).removeClass("over"); });
    });
}
```

Comment: Many Thanks for your prompt & correct answer - it worked a treat.